# How can I work out the hopf-algebra action corresponding to a group action on an affine scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, hopf-algebras, affine-schemes, algebraic-stacks

Consider the affine scheme
$$
X = \text{Spec}\left( \frac{\mathbb{C}[t,x]}{(x^2 - t)} \right)
$$
If I take the projection onto the $t$-axis, there is an obvious $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action switching the fibers. This can be described by sending $x \mapsto -x$. How can I find the hopf-algebra action (maybe co-action) of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[s]/(s^2 - 1)) = \mathbb{Z}/2$ on the algebra defining $X$? I want to try and get an explicit diagram of the cogroupoid of algebras.

My first guess is the action (co-action?) sends
$$
x \mapsto -x\otimes s \text{ and } t \mapsto t\otimes s
$$
for the target map
$$
\frac{\mathbb{C}[t,x]}{(x^2 - t)} \to \frac{\mathbb{C}[t,x]}{(x^2 - t)}\otimes_\mathbb{C} \frac{\mathbb{C}[s]}{(s^2 - 1)}
$$
and
$$
x\mapsto x \text{ and } t\mapsto t
$$
for the source map.

Also, I think the identity section should be the map 
$$
\frac{\mathbb{C}[t,x]}{(x^2 - t)}\otimes_\mathbb{C} \frac{\mathbb{C}[s]}{(s^2 - 1)} \to \frac{\mathbb{C}[t,x]}{(x^2 - t)}
$$
sending
$$
s\to 1
$$